# Occurrences of each arbitrary number of integers (Java) - Build not running class

Tags: java

I am working on a make up assignment that reads an arbitrary number of integers that are in the range of 0 to 100 inclusive and counts how many occurrences of each are entered.

Though I am sure the IntegerCount is working correctly right in it's current state, I don't know how to get it to implement within the main function. During Builds, I keep entering integers but get no results from the neither the account, getOccurance, or print objects, unless I attempt to add an integer out of bounds for a exception. Am I missing something?

Main Class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        IntegerCount intCount = new IntegerCount();
        int submit;
        System.out.println("Type Integers: ");
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            submit = input.nextInt();
            intCount.account(submit); // Should be where the integers are being
                                        // sent to the IntegerCount class
        }
        intCount.print();
    }
}
```

IntegerCount Class:

```
public class IntegerCount {
    private int max = 100;
    int[] integer = new int[max];

    public void account(int val) {
        integer[val] = integer[val] - 1;
    }

    public int getOccurrences(int val) {
        return integer[val];
    }

    public void print() {
        for (int i = 0; i < integer.length; i++) {
            if (integer[i] != 0) {
                System.out.println("number of occurrences of " + i + "occurs " + integer[i] + "times");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that your  `while (input.hasNext())` goes into an endless loop reading integers. I suggest you to read the number of integers in the range of 0 to 100 first and then count them accordingly. I have modified your main method as follows to count the occurances of `numberOfIntegersToCount` number of integers:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        IntegerCount intCount = new IntegerCount();

        // number of integers to count in the range of 0 to 100
        int numberOfIntegersToCount = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Type Integers: ");

        // loop until all integers are read
        while (numberOfIntegersToCount > 0){
            int submit = input.nextInt();
            intCount.account(submit); //Should be where the integers are being sent to the IntegerCount class
            numberOfIntegersToCount--;
        }
        intCount.print();

    }
}
```

You `account` actually counts in negative. I also modified `account` method as follows:

```
public void account(int val) {
     integer[val] = integer[val] + 1;
}
```

Since you say:

> 0 to 100 inclusive

Your current `IntegerCount` code will not work for input 100. For 100 `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` will be thrown.